# Common Data Services Logic App Connector or Service Endpoint for publishing changes to ServiceBus

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365, common-data-service

I am looking for a resilient way to publish changes on Dynamics 365. I have done a POC using the below methods.

1. Use logic apps to connect to Dynamics 365 instance using Common Data Services connector which gets triggered upon any changes on connected entity. I have tried disabling the logic app to simulate the scenario in case the logic app fails for some reason. I found out the logic app does not trigger for the updates done while the logic app was disabled when enabled back. Is that expected behavior? I am thinking from resiliency perspective.
2. Registered a service end point to publish the changes to service bus. I found the messages published were verbose and its tedious to work out the changes by dissecting the message.

What is the recommended way to publish the changes on the D365 entity?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 1 and yes logic app will not get triggered when it is in disabled state.

1. Use logic apps to connect to Dynamics 365 instance using Common Data Services connector which gets triggered upon any changes on connected entity. I have tried disabling the logic app to simulate the scenario in case the logic app fails for some reason. I found out the logic app does not trigger for the updates done while the logic app was disabled when enabled back. Is that expected behavior? I am thinking from resiliency perspective.

Another advantage is that you can prepare json object in a way you want to send the message to logic app. Registering service endpoint would post entire remote context data to the service bus which is a bit difficult to parse.

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful